# PHP post file multipart form

Tags: php, curl

I need to post a file to an API via a standard multipart form post request.
What I have so far is this:

```
$url = 'http://foo.co.uk/rest/v1/api_gateway/file';
$header = array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');
$fields = array('files[]' => '@' . 'movie.mp4');

$resource = curl_init();
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

$result = curl_exec($resource);
curl_close($resource);

echo '<pre>' , print_r($result) , '</pre>';
```

But I don't get any response, It should come back with more information, does my code look OK?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this myself, but you could try to use CurlFile.

http://www.php.net//manual/en/class.curlfile.php

Not quite sure how to use it though but hopefully it points you in the right direction.